# Delete address Ajax Opencart 2.1.x

Tags: php, ajax, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am trying to delete address by using ajax call and data type as json:

Ajax call is as below:

```
$(".delete a").on('click', function() {
    url: 'index.php?route=account/address/delete',
    type: 'post',
    data: "address_id="+addid,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(html) {
        $("#msg").html('Deleted Address Successfully '); 
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        delcheckbox.html('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>');
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

and in `account/address/delete` i wrote a new Post request condition as below:

```
public function delete() {
  /* Opencart Pre written functions are here */
  if (isset($this->request->post['address_id'])&&$this->validateDelete()) {
      $json = array();
      $this->model_account_address->deleteAddress($this->request->post['address_id']);
      /* Unset Session variables same as get function of opencart */

      /*to get json as response*/
      $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
      $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
  }
}
```

When i execute ajax call then address is deleted successfully but as a reponse the `error` block of ajax is shown and error says as below screeenshot

[image]

Please suggest.
and please explain how operations `pre.customer.delete.address` and `post.customer.delete.address` work??

Comment: Your error isn't readable. It's clearly an entire page that you're ajaxing instead of just a json response. Said page seems to be giving off a javascript error. Are you sure the ajax link is being handled correctly? Isn't your error saying (somewhere where we can't see, in the body?) that you're on the 404 page?
- I also don't see an ajax call start-off in your code. You put `$.ajax` parameters within an on.click function, not within a `$.ajax` function

Comment: i get this error only and if it is 404 then how address is deleted

Comment: I know you're getting this error, but we can not scroll down. You are clearly getting a page returned, what does it say in the content? in the <body>? When you scroll further down?

Comment: yes it is a page but i am not generating this in POST request..

Comment: That's why I'm curious as to *why* you're getting a page back. When I get a page back, it's generally 1 of 2 things:
1 ) I'm calling a function within the rendering framework,. 2 ) I'm getting a 404. or 3 ) I'm getting a "You're not authorised to be here" error. - it seems to me that the syntaxError: unexpected token < is because the OK makes it invalid html (the rest of the response)

Comment: i found that delete page has function $this->getList() that can return page. i removed this.. and now i am getting error unexected end of output... :) loking further.. if u are opencart expert then please let me know

Comment: There is no more error :)  Thanks,,,,

Comment: I'll put out on answer so you can mark this as resolved.
I have made an entire custom framework upon opencart 2.0, but this was just a little over a year ago (when it was just released). So, at one point I pretty much knew opencart by heart, but I don't think I can be of much use without diving back into it again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a page returned in your response. This indicates you might be getting a 404, another kind of error, or are calling onto a function that renders a page. Make sure none of this is happening.

Comment: my second question need to answered also

Comment: It seems opencart has little to no functional documentation. Unfortunately, the only way for you to find out is to either wait for someone who happens to know this, or to simply find the functions and read through what they do... (That's how I did it when I started out in opencart)

Comment: what is your custom framework?? where i can download

Comment: Haha, you can't, unfortunately. The company I had made it for went bankrupt. It was meant to improve opencart. (I had inserted things like Macro's, a template-editor, better management for a lot of things, etc.)
Anyway, I wasn't allowed to take it home, so I didn't. When the company went bankrupt I never got the chance to save my old work.